# Confused about Heroku's PG database max size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I run heroku pg:info, I see the following:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 5
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-06-17 14:38 UTC
Data Size:   9.1 MB
Tables:      4
Rows:        9662/10000 (In compliance, close to row limit)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

How can I see where are those rows? I mean, if I do a count of all my models, I just get 4000 rows, and I fail to see where are the rest. Any way to get more details on this in Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query (taken from [Understanding Postgres Performance](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2012/10/01/understanding-postgres-performance/)).

```
SELECT 
  relname, 
  100 * idx_scan / (seq_scan + idx_scan) percent_of_times_index_used, 
  n_live_tup rows_in_table
FROM 
  pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE 
    seq_scan + idx_scan > 0 
ORDER BY 
  n_live_tup DESC;
```

It's also included in the [pg-extras plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras) as `pg:index_usage`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend connecting to your database using an external tool such as [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/).

You can retrieve database info with:

`$ heroku pg:credentials DATABASE`